# Add blank rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am looking for a code that could insert a variable no. of blank rows (4-6) after each row with observations (there are currently 5 rows in the table), so that I can fill/add observations to the blank rows. I came across the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  split(df$id) %>% 
  Map(rbind, ., NA) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .) %>%
  mutate(id = rep(df$id, each = 2))
```

However, replacing 2 with 4 in "each" returns an error message,

> "Error: Column `ID` must be length 10 (the number of rows) or one, not
>   20"

Any advise how to work around to get past the no. 2?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: We need to see `df` to understand why that code does/doesn't work. But I would reconsider the entire approach. Data frames are not like spreadsheets; there should be no need to "edit" them manually after generating them. Better to write code which creates all the values at the outset; or append rows and sort on an index.

Comment: @Arindam Pal, Try `df %>% 
   split(df$id) %>% 
    Map(rbind, ., NA,NA,NA) %>% 
    do.call(rbind, .) %>%
    mutate(id = rep(df$id, each = 4))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one technique that works on base R, under the premise that taking an `NA`th of a frame returns a row that is filled with `NA` values.

```r
dat <- head(iris)
unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)), c, rep(NA, 2)))
#  [1]  1 NA NA  2 NA NA  3 NA NA  4 NA NA  5 NA NA  6 NA NA
dat[ unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)), c, rep(NA, 2))), ]
#       Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1              5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# NA              NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# NA.1            NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# 2              4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# NA.2            NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# NA.3            NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# 3              4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# NA.4            NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# NA.5            NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# 4              4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# NA.6            NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# NA.7            NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# 5              5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# NA.8            NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# NA.9            NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# 6              5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# NA.10           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# NA.11           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
```

(Row names might be distracting, but they can easily be removed and/or changed/updated.)

The number of rows are fixed here at 2 per row of actual observations. If you need to vary it, switch from `sapply` to `mapply`/`unlist` with another vector argument:

```r
unlist(mapply(function(a,b) c(a, rep(NA, b)), seq_len(nrow(dat)), c(2,1,2,1,2,1)))
#  [1]  1 NA NA  2 NA  3 NA NA  4 NA  5 NA NA  6 NA
dat[ unlist(mapply(function(a,b) c(a, rep(NA, b)), seq_len(nrow(dat)), c(2,1,2,1,2,1))), ]
#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1             5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# NA             NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# NA.1           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# 2             4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# NA.2           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# 3             4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# NA.3           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# NA.4           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# 4             4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# NA.5           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# 5             5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# NA.6           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# NA.7           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
# 6             5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# NA.8           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
```